# If Superman's blood came in contact with a human, would this be dangerous?

Tags: dc, superman

Since Superman does not bleed very often, this may never have come up. My thinking is that components of his immune system might attack human skin, etc. as being foreign with perhaps catastrophic consequences.

Perhaps, however, Superman or another Kryptonian has actually given blood to a human for a transfusion with purely a beneficial effect.

Comment: Superman has done this loads of times. His blood is universally acceptable and highly beneficial to humans, if memory serves

Comment: @Valorum does not make very much sense, but glad to hear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Superman gives blood to humans (Lois Lane and Lana Lang) on several occasions. In early stories his blood confers resistance to illness and makes the recipient feel suspiciously strong.

> [image]
> <sub><sup>[**Superman Vol.1 #6**](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Superman_Vol_1_6)</sup></sub>

and

> [image]
> <sub><sup>**[Superman Vol.1 #363](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Superman_Vol_1_363)**</sup></sub>

Superman's blood temporarily confers super powers on recipients.

> [image]
> <sub><sup>[**Superman's Girl Friend, Lois Lane Vol.1 #17**](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Superman%27s_Girl_Friend,_Lois_Lane_Vol_1_17)</sup></sub>

As does Supergirl's blood.

> [image]
> <sub><sup>[**Action Comics Vol.1 #321**](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Action_Comics_Vol_1_321#Synopsis_for_Supergirl:_%22The_Enemy_Supergirl%22)</sup></sub>

Comment: Hey, wait!  How'd they stick those needles into him?!

Comment: This is much better than the immune cells in Superman's blood instantly devouring the recipient.

Comment: @DavidW - He tears open his skin with a fingernail

Comment: That Doctor should realize 0 blood is just the absence of A or B or both A,B proteins.  Which makes 0 a universal donor and AB a universal receiver as AB won't freak out and coagulate if it sees just A or B proteins (or nothing).  So I personally wouldn't call that 4 types.  It's 3 types and an absence. Humbug.

Comment: Is Superman being a dick? What if Lana tries to sit down in a frictionless costume she'll slide right out of any chair!

Comment: @lucasbachmann - So you're entirely OK with the man leaping tall buildings in his underwear, but heaven forfend a doctor misspeaks.

Comment: @lucasbachmann That is only one blood-group system though: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_type#Blood_group_systems From what little I know, there is the Rh blood group system, in which you can find the Rhnull, which is an even more universal blood donor than the O from the ABO blood group system. I don't know which one these scientists are using though.

Comment: @lucasbachmann What about a papasan or a bucket seat? Actually it says friction-proof, not frictionless, as in friction cannot harm it just like fireproof means fire cannot harm it.